# RandomReal inside a loop

Tags: random, procedural-programming

I want to perform the following series summation:
$$\sum_{j=1}^5 \exp\left[{-\beta \, \left(\text{En} + \frac{\Delta \, X}{Num}  \right)}\right] \cos{\left(\text{En} + \frac{\Delta \, X \, T}{Num}  \right)},$$

where $X$ is a random real number, which takes a different value for each of the 5 terms in the series, in the interval $[0,1]$. I am trying to implement the same using the following code:

```
Sum[ E^{-\[Beta] {En + \[CapitalDelta]/ Num RandomReal[]} } {Cos[{En + \[CapitalDelta]/ Num RandomReal[]} t]}, {J, 1, 5}]
```

Here the problem I am encountering is that the random number takes different values for the argument of the exponential and the argument of the cosine, while my case involves the same random number for both. How do I enforce that the argument X for a term in the series is the same, and not two different random reals within the same term in the series?

Comment: Use a `With` and set the `RandomReal[]` in there `Sum[With[{X = RandomReal[]},E^{-\[Beta] {En + \[CapitalDelta]/ Num X}} {Cos[{En + \[CapitalDelta]/Num X} t]}], {J, 1, 5}]`

Comment: @flinty Thanks, that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[beta_, en_, x_, delta_, num_, t_] :=
 Exp[-beta (en + x*delta)]*Cos[en + delta*x*t/num]
Total[f[β, En, X, Δ, #, t] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 5]]
```

Comment: Yes. Use the procedural `Total` rather than the analytic `Sum`. Sometimes `Sum` figures out that you are using it procedurally, but it can get lost attempting symbolic analysis.

Comment: @John, indeed `Total[]` is appropriate here (especially if you use `Method -> "CompensatedSummation"`), but `Sum[]` can also be coerced to do no symbolic analysis at all via `Method -> "Procedural"`.